# Material circular button in Android?

Tags: java, android, material-design

Take a look at this list item in the CyanogenMod Music app:

[image]

Which `View` is being used for that settings button? It couldn't be an `ImageButton` because when I press it, it creates a circular ripple:

[image]

Perhaps one way to do this is inflating a menu button in `Toolbar` inside the list. But calling `inflateMenu()` requires minimum API level 21. What other ways can be used to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: yes, but this isn't `ActionBar` or `Toolbar`, it's a list item.

Comment: All you need it to define a circular ripple drawable - or even an unbounded one. Unbounded ripples default to a circular shape. Are you asking how you can define the shape of a ripple?

Comment: Please demonstrate the xml as an answer, I'll try it once I get home. Thanks!

Comment: Check out : https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have a circular ripple you can define it in two ways.

1. You can use an unbounded ripple - If you don't define a shape or mask the ripple defaults to a circular shape
2. You can specifically define the shape of the mask as circular

---

An unbounded ripple is defined very simply like this:

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

If you touch the `View` it will create basic circular ripple which for example is used on the default Android lock screen when you enter a PIN.

---

However unbounded ripples by definition don't have any defined bounds and as such are not always what you want. If you just want to specifically define the shape and size of the ripple you can use a mask. This has the advantage that the item used to define the shape will not be drawn. It works like this:

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <!-- If you give an item this mask id then it will only be used to determine the shape of -->
    <!-- ripple, but will not be drawn in any way -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <!-- android:shape defines the shape of the ripple. I use oval for a circular one, -->
        <!-- but there are also rectangle, line, ring -->
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

---

You can choose from those two options above - which ever one you like best. Just assign the ripple to an `ImageView` like this and it should look pretty much like the image in your question:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple"
    android:src="@drawable/your_icon"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

I added the `clickable` attribute above so the ripple will be enabled even if you don't assign a click listener to the `ImageView`. As long as you assign a click listener you don't really need it.

Comment: although this is certainly a correct way to do this, it's probably worth mentioning that it needs minimum API level 21.

Comment: @HendraAnggrian Of course. The `RippleDrawable` was added in API level 21. The simplest fallback is a simple selector drawable for previous API levels.